# Jquery tag editor is not working while populating initializing jquery array from database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a tagging system on my project. i am using **[This github tagedit plugin](https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit)** in my website for the tagging system.they are using jquery codes like `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` etc(their own).there is a php code in this tool which will initialize an array with tag names and tag id.after this initialization jquery will handle all client side work(tagging facilities).

now the problem is they initialized that array manually in their code.but for obvious reason i cant do that.i have to initialize this array dynamically from database.whenever am trying to initialize it dynamically the whole thing is not working.i debugged it a lot and i found that after initialization in the next step they are checking for `if(isset($_GET['term']))` and this `isset($_GET['term'])` is always returning false.why??

**here is their code ::**

```
$autocompletiondata = array(
   3 => 'Hazel Grouse',
   4 => 'Common Quail',
   5 => 'Common Pheasant',
   6 => 'Northern Shoveler',
   7 => 'Greylag Goose',
   8 => 'Barnacle Goose',
   9 => 'Lesser Spotted Woodpecker',
   10 => 'Eurasian Pygmy-Owl',
   11 => 'Dunlin',
   13 => 'Black Scoter',
   14 => 'Eurasian Wryneck',
   15 => 'Little Owl',
   16 => 'Eurasian Curlew',
);

if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
   $result = array();
   foreach($autocompletiondata as $key => $value) {
      if(strlen($_GET['term']) == 0 || strpos(strtolower($value), strtolower($_GET['term'])) !== false) {
         $result[] = '{"id":'.$key.',"label":"'.$value.'","value":"'.$value.'"}';
    }
}
echo "[".implode(',', $result)."]";
}
```

this above code is working absolutely fine.the whole tagging system is working fine.but when i am trying to initialize that array dynamically from database it is not working.the whole tagging system stops working.

**here is my code ::**

```
//$link is database connection link
$query = mysqli_query($link,"select id,tag_name from tags order by no_of_times_used desc");
$autocompletiondata=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) 
{ 
$autocompletiondata +=array($row->id => $row->tag_name);
}

if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
   $result = array();
   foreach($autocompletiondata as $key => $value) {
      if(strlen($_GET['term']) == 0 || strpos(strtolower($value), strtolower($_GET['term'])) !== false) {
          $result[] = '{"id":'.$key.',"label":"'.$value.'","value":"'.$value.'"}';
      }
   }
echo "[".implode(',', $result)."]";
}
```

now as i said this above code is not working, the whole tagging system stopped working now

**NOTE :** i have tried my code in variety of ways like initialize the array with in while loop in this (`$autocompletiondata[$row->id] = $row->tag_name;`) fashion and not declaring `$autocompletiondata=array();` outside `while loop`.lots of attempts but none of them worked for me.

what i can assure is mu `dbConfig.php` is absolutely fine because my other interactions with database is working perfectly.

now my question is how to solve this problem?how should i initialize the array with values from database to make this tagging system work ?

Comment: `isset($_GET['term'])` seems to be Php, not Jquery

Answer (score 0):

The [isset](http://php.net/isset) function checks if a variable is declared or not. This function returns false when a given variable doesn't exist.

`$_GET` is an array of url params.
So, if `isset($_GET['term'])` returns false, this means the current url is not containing a parameter with the name `term`. So, try to add something like `yourlink.com?term=something` and hit ENTER...

In addition, to initialize your array with data from the database, you should write this

```
  //---
 $query = mysqli_query($link,"select id,tag_name from tags order by no_of_times_used desc");
 $autocompletiondata=array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) 
 { 
   $autocompletiondata[$row->id]=$row->tag_name;
 }
 //-----
```

Comment: can u tell me the reason why it is not working???because when i am trying with their default code i dont need to do thing like `yourlink.com?term=something`

Comment: the way you are initializing the array it will create only one row.i mean only last object value will be there after execution of entire while loop..no?

Comment: I think the problem is because you don't initialize the array with the good way! Please see my last edits!

Comment: the way you are initializing the array it will create only one row.i mean only last object value will be there after execution of entire while loop..no?

Comment: `$autocompletiondata[]=...` means that each row is appended to existing object. The concatenation operator `+=` does not make sense.

Comment: `+=` initializing fine i checked it...but in your case it will create array of arrays..right??..something like `autocompletiondata([0]=>array([0]=>....[1]=>...))`..right??but it is not how they are using the array

Comment: Sorry but Have you tried my last edited answer? I changed the code from `$autocompletiondata[]=array($row->id,$row->tag_name);` to `$autocompletiondata[$row->id]=$row->tag_name;`

Comment: yes. i tried it...i mentioned it already in my question ody..it was my first approach..but surprisingly it didnt work